# How to control table and picture position while using python-docx to generate MS-word

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-docx

I want to put my picture and table(only 1 cell) like below:
[Click here to see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNmar.png)
I have to use such table because python-docx can't handle text-box yet.   Basically I need to **put my table beside my picture**, not below or upper. I find that paragraph.run has `add_picture()` method to add picture at the end of paragraph, but not `add_table()` method to add one more table. Anyone know how to achieve this

Comment: How about a two-cell table (one row, two columns) with the picture in the left cell and the table in the right cell.

Comment: This seems to be a solution, I will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have tried so many ways to put a picture into a table ,that is what i do deal with my problem, you may find something you can use

```
from docx import Document
document = Document
table = document.add_table(rows=2, cols=3)
# set the whole table in the center position
table.alignment = WD_TABLE_ALIGNMENT.CENTER
row_cell = table.add_row().cells
# choice one row
**row_pic = row_cell[0]**  
# clear blank area
**row_pic._tc.clear_content()**
# use paragraph function
**pic_run = row_pic.add_paragraph().add_run()**
# insert a picture path as a str into a cell from a table
**pic_run.add_picture('./picture/{}'.format("picture_name.jpg"), width=Inches(5))**
```